# Remove "algorithm X :" in an algorithme2 caption

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I tried to use `caption*` :

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered, ruled,vlined,linesnumbered, french, onelanguage]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        $test$\;
        \caption{alg}
    \end{algorithm}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
        $test$\;
        \caption*{alg}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But it didn't work as intended :
[image]

Because I want only `alg` to be displayed in the caption
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `\NoCaptionOfAlgo`   You can use it in the preamble or locally. `\RestoreCaptionOfAlgo` will restore the correct captions.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered, ruled,vlined,linesnumbered, french, onelanguage]{algorithm2e}


\NoCaptionOfAlgo % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame 1}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
        $test$\;
            \caption{alg A }
        \end{algorithm}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            $test$\;
            \caption{alg B}
        \end{algorithm}
        \RestoreCaptionOfAlgo % restore the caption
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
        $test$\;
        \caption{alg C}
    \end{algorithm}
    
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the package caption, in the doc Algoritm2e p.22-23.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered, ruled,vlined,linesnumbered, french, onelanguage]{algorithm2e}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 1}
        \SetAlgorithmName{}{}{}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            %\TitleOfAlgo{alg}
            $test$\;
            \caption{alg}
        \end{algorithm}

        \SetAlgoRefName{}
        \SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            $test$\;
            \caption{alg}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]